# How to connect to mqtt.2030.ltsapis.goog?

Tags: google-cloud-iot

For connecting to mqtt.2030.ltsapis.goog, do I use Server Authentication or Server/Client Authentication. If using Server/Client Authentication, I need to send client certificate and private key. Where should I get the Client cert and the Private Key?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For generating **CA certificates** and the corresponding **private keys**, please refer to the following docs [Publishing over the MQTT bridge](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge) and [Verifying device credentials](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/verifying-credentials). Also watch [Getting started with Google cloud IoT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIxiYMOWgrg) and [Qwik Start](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iRZzqpvARbc) video for more reference. Please let me know if you have any specific issues while generating the certificates.